# Science fiction short story about mysterious phenomenon caused by alien artifact

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Trying to recall a science fiction short story which begins with the protagonist being asked to join a husband and wife team on a trip to South America (IIRC) to investigate a mysterious phenomenon (I think it was a constant, never-ending wind) in some high mountain valley type of locality. The strange phenomenon is discovered to be caused by some kind of alien artifact, I think a miniature black hole or space warp may have been involved.

I am pretty confident this story isn't too old, and that I read it in a "Best SF of the Year" anthology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You say it "isn't too old" but can you give us an approximate date when you read it, or at least say not later than XXXX?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ["Trapalanda"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42500) by Charles Sheffield. I read it in *The Best Time Travel Stories of the 20th Century*, edited by Harry Turtledove with Martin H. Greenberg. I don't have the book, but here is the abstract I wrote for myself after reading it.

> A man lived in Patagonia for many years and tried to explore a
> particularly mysterious area. Now he lives in Europe. A wealthy
> American man pays this man well to accompany him back down there. The
> wealthy man says he has a model of weather that works worldwide except
> for an area of Patagonia which has weird weather patterns. When they
> get there, they find a device which opens a wormhole to some unknown
> place far away; the effect on weather is a side effect from slight
> mistuning of the device (which otherwise works perfectly). The wealthy
> man and the wife of the other man go through the wormhole; the other
> man goes partway and turns back, as a result of which he ages several
> decades in the few minutes it takes him to struggle back to our side.
> In a week or two he returns to the site to attempt to go through; the
> result is not part of the story.

Comment: The story is available at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v11n06_1987-06/page/n82/mode/1up

Comment: I enjoyed discovering and reading this new-to-me story.